# How do you calculate the vertical angle from a 3d rotation matrix or a quaternion?

Tags: rotations, quaternions

I've got the rotation matrix and quaternion of a mobile device. I'm trying to calculate the vertical angle from it. What I'm trying to get is for example 0° if the device is held in portrait mode and 90° in landscape mode.

Any help would be appreciated. I'm sorry if this was asked before, I don't have any experience with this and didn't really know what to search for.

Comment: Try starting [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many sign conventions associated with rotation matrices, quaternions, and Euler angles. It can get confusing.

But hopefully you just want the angle $\theta$ between the space-fixed $z$-axis and the body-fixed $z'$-axis, and presumably your $3\times3$ rotation matrix $\mathbf{A}$ is defined such that $\mathbf{r}'=\mathbf{A}\cdot\mathbf{r}$ (or the same equation, but with the transpose of $\mathbf{A}$). In that case $\cos\theta=A_{33}$ because it is just the scalar product between the original, and rotated, $(0,0,1)$ vectors. So take the arccos of the $3,3$ element of the rotation matrix.

I advise you to double check that this makes sense for your definitions and coordinate systems!